# Specifying additional data elements for TreeViewItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a TreeView that has multiple levels. I would like to assign the top level items as "Parent" items so that when they are clicked on I can see that set property and change which tab is selected in a TabControl.

So far the only useful thing I can see to set without screwing things up is the `Uid`, is there any way to add extra properties to the TreeViewItems? I am thinking of when I worked in Javascript and CSS and how you could add extra `data` tags to any element and wasn't sure if you can do that in C#

```
var serverGroupList = ServerDB.ExecuteDB("SELECT * FROM server_groups");
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serverGroupList);
dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

foreach (var item in dynJson)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Adding ServerGroup: " + item.name);
    ComboboxItem DropdownItem = new ComboboxItem();
    DropdownItem.Text = item.name.ToString();
    DropdownItem.Value = item.id;

    ServerGroupDropdown.Items.Add(DropdownItem);

    treeItem = new TreeViewItem();
    treeItem.Header = item.name;
    treeItem.Uid = item.id;
    var serverListResults = ServerDB.ExecuteDB("SELECT * FROM servers WHERE group_id = " + item.id);
    var serversJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serverListResults);
    dynamic servers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serversJSON);
    foreach (var server in servers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Adding: " + server.name);
        treeItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = server.name, Uid = server.id });
    }
    ServerList.Items.Add(treeItem);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wpf TreeView can do much more than just show text Header of each item. Please study this CodeProject article to get the overview: [Basic Understanding of Tree View in WPF](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124644/Basic-Understanding-of-Tree-View-in-WPF). When using bindings and templates it becomes unnecessary to create TreeViewItems in code behind (All necessary properties are stored in the data items. TreeView generates TreeViewItems automatically for each data item, and there is 1:1 relation between data item and TreeViewItem.DataContext)

Still, to continue with your current approach, store any additional data in `DataContext` property:

```
treeItem = new TreeViewItem();
treeItem.Header = item.name;
treeItem.Uid = item.id;
treeItem.DataContext = item;
```

and

```
treeItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem { Header = server.name, Uid = server.id, DataContext = server });
```

Comment: You can also set the Tag property, which is helpful when multiple TVIs have the same tag, as you can easily select all TVI with a certain tag.